# How do I change the default index page in Apache?

Tags: html, apache, indexing, default

I would like to change the default web page that shows up when I browse my site. I currently have a reporting program running, and it outputs a file called index.html. I cannot change what it calls the file. Therefore, my landing page must be called something else. Right now, when I browse my site it takes me to the reporting page.

From what I see, whatever you call index.html it will pull that up as your default. I want to change that to landing.html. How do I do this?

I am a folder (Folding @ Home). The reporting program is HFM.net. HFM can output an html file with my current folding statistics. It names the html file index. I do not want that to be my default home page. I would like a menu-like landing where I can choose if I want to see my stats, or something else. The website is at /home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website (landing.html and hfm's index.html are here). Apache2 is in its default directory.

I'm also running Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: By default, DirectoryIndex  is index.html but the file is absent. Just create index.html in /var/www/html and you will see your contents.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I recommend using `.htaccess`. You only need to add:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

or whatever page name you want to have for it.

**EDIT**: basic htaccess tutorial.

1. Create `.htaccess` file in the directory where you want to change the index file.

- no extension
- `.` in front, to ensure it is a "hidden" file

  Enter the line above in there. There will likely be many, many other things you will add to this (AddTypes for webfonts / media files, caching for headers, gzip declaration for compression, etc.), but that one line declares your new "home" page.

2. Set server to allow reading of `.htaccess` files (may only be needed on your localhost, if your hosting servce defaults to allow it as most do)

Assuming you have access, go to your server's enabled site location. I run a Debian server for development, and the default site setup is at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` for Debian / Ubuntu. Not sure what server you run, but just search for "sites-available" and go into the "default" document. In there you will see an entry for Directory. Modify it to look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart your apache server. Again, not sure about your server, but the command on Debian / Ubuntu is:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Technically you only need to reload, but I restart just because I feel safer with a full refresh like that.

Once that is done, your site should be reading from your .htaccess file, and you should have a new default home page! A side note, if you have a sub-directory that runs a site (like an admin section or something) and you want to have a different "home page" for that directory, you can just plop another `.htaccess` file in that sub-site's root and it will overwrite the declaration in the parent.

Comment: How do I use htaccess?

My landing.html file is not in the same directory.

Comment: Hmmm... so what I'm supposed to do is create a file named ".htaccess" in my root directory? My root directory is something else as I changed it in the httpd.conf (and I added an "Include httpd.conf" in apache2.conf. Would that be the root directory to which you're referring?

Check my edit in the original post for my situation.

Comment: when i refer to root directoy, i mean the root directory of the **site** (in your case, `/home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website`), not ur comp. edited the verbiage in my answer, i can see how that could be misunderstood.

Comment: did u reload the server? and also, since u did a custom site location, did u create a different enabled site than "default"? because that is the one u need to mod, if so.

Comment: Actually everything is working now.

Any idea how I would reference another html file? I'm trying to do it within an image. I'm getting a 404 error.

<a href="/home/tyler/Documents/hfm/website/index.html"><img src= "fahlogo.png" /></a>

Comment: you might want to pose this as a separate question, with more explanation and code provided.

Comment: service should be singular in the restart/reload command line

Comment: Instead of `service apache2 reload && sudo service apache2 restart` you can just pass `service apache2 restart`. When you restart Apache it reloads itself automatically, just as on normal service start.

Comment: Instead of using restart you can use graceful (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful)

Comment: After some headaches, I had to set AllowOverride to `All` for getting this working.
Btw, the file you have to edit is not such `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` but `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Can you please explain what each line is doing? The suggested edits to the configuration file are causing errors for me.

Answer (score 27):

You can also set DirectoryIndex in apache's httpd.conf file.

CentOS keeps this file in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
Debian: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Open the file in your text editor and find the line starting with DirectoryIndex

To load landing.html as a default (but index.html if that's not found) change this line to read:

```
DirectoryIndex  landing.html index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  When providing http://server/appDirectory I got a directory listing instead of index.html even though I had

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
</IfModule>
```

in my httpd.conf file.

My solution was to uncomment the

```
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
```

line in httpd.conf

Apache version:  2.4

Comment: Suppose you are not the owner but on a shared host and not in control of apache. How can you configure an htaccess to override the default indexes layout they have specified?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you can add in file:

`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`

line

`DirectoryIndex myhomepage.htm`

and then restart apache service

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: Hi, this is a comment, not an helpful answer. bu sure to read [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Why is that? This is the only solution for me. And I shared it. I probably didn't explain it well.

Comment: Because you say "now it doesn't help", and there is already an accepted answer with 107 upvotes . So, looks like a comment, not an aswer  that addresses original question :-). I wanted to help you better understand stackoverflow rules!

Answer (score 0):

In Unbuntu, you can update the default page on a site-by-site basis with the site config files eg:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/your.domain.conf`

Same syntax for the key line in the file, eg mine is;

`DirectoryIndex  default.htm index.htm`

Then don't forget to enable and reload:

```
sudo a2ensite your.domain.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```