# Wordpress not running index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

When going to my server IP it displays a blank page. If I log onto the server try: php index.php I get the full site content printed in the console.  Adding phpinfo(); to the top of index.php still displays the the full php information sheet. All files and directories are available in a web browser to the degree you would expect.

The possible root cause recursively changing the group of the file holding all the site content.

How does one get the server to display the full site content again?

Comment: Add `index.php` to the list of files displayed in order within a directory?

Comment: Where does one set such a list? I was under the impression that index.php was displayed automatically. This is indicated by adding phpinfo(); to the index.php file displaying full php info sheet.

Comment: You can change it using htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache

Comment: I have already played around with .htaccess but it just loads index.php with the same, blank content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Webserver Error-Log? For Apache2 its /var/log/apache2/error.log if not specified in vHost-Config. Normaly if there is an Error which will not be shown in cause of PHP-Configuration you will see there.

Also be aware that php-cli which is the "php" Command on the shell and the php-module for Webserver have to sperate Config-Files so if you have changed something to fit the requirements of Wordpress you have to do it for (on Debian) /etc/php5/cli/ (for shell) and /etc/php5/apache2/ (for http - via apache) as well!

Comment: Cheers for the answer, the error log's entries are all just saying that the server has resumed normal operation and the times correlate to when I restarted the server.

Comment: I have a really laggy connection into the server and have inherited the site from someone else. Can you suggest any particular settings I should check or best just run a sdiff?