# How can I handle in PHP a subfolder's index.php as main index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I read this question: [How to set an index page in a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231919/how-to-set-an-index-page-in-a-subfolder?fbclid=IwAR2OwNGxqeDxUaKrD-6vlhr2OpPfPIB2PfclTunHYiXG5x4Kn3xiO_emiiM).
I want to make like this, I have these folders and files:

```
index.php
items/
items/index.php
```

and I want, when I search for "items/general", then items/index.php handles it, not index.php. I tried to make a .htacces file in /items/.htacces, with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ items/index.php [L]
```

BUT when I search for "items/general", it gives a 404 error, like this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

(and my items/index.php includes a code to send html to all request)

Why doesn't works it?

Comment: Can you spell out what your RewriteRule above should do?

Comment: I want to forward the request for example "items/general" to items/index.php, not the index.php in the root.

Comment: Yes I understood what you want. What I'm asking is, do you understand what your RewriteRule says there? And, how it's going to accomplish what you want? The regular expression reads: `^` start-of-subject `/` forward-slash `?` 0 or 1 of them `$` end-of-subject. What all would that match? (Hint: Empty _or_ one forward-slash. Nothing else.) For reference: [mod_rewrite / Regular Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like that :

```
  RewriteRule  items/ items/index.php [L]
```

if you want a genaric rule /any-folder/any-file.php to /any-folder/index.php

```
  RewriteRule  (\w+)/ $1/index.php [L]
```