# Access script without changing url

Tags: php, redirect

From http://localhost/ I want to access http://localhost/1.php

How can I make it so I can access the 1.php file in the browser without changing the url?

Comment: do you want to import the content of 1.php to index.php ? or rewrite url ?

Comment: Rewrite url if it's possible.

Comment: Use an ajax request to load the contents of the file onto the current page

Comment: Use rewrite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache

Answer (score 1):

Use `DirectoryIndex 1.php` in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: I have more than 1 file, I don't want to make my 1.php the index file.

Comment: @Lurrdock can you give us some other examples so we can understand what you want ?

Comment: I just want to access that file without changing the url. How can I explain this? When I want to click and open the 1.php file from http://localhost/ I want to open it and the URL to be still http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to get content of different PHP files and display that on your landing page

Comment: Simplest way is to use jQuery JavaScript library. Then you can make something like this:

    `$.get('1.php').done(function(data) { $('#content').html(data); });`

I'm assuming there's an element with ID "content" on you HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple example:
index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Ajax example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#page1").click(function(){
                $('#result').load('page1.html');
            }); 

            $("#page2").click(function(){
                $('#result').load('page2.html');
            });
            //and so on
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="page1" href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a id="page2" href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a id="page3" href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
        <div id="result" style="clear:both;">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Assume you have page1.html with the content

```
<h1>Hi this is page1</h1>
```

The click on link "one" will fill the div with content of page1.html and so on

Whit this type of implementation you should factory the other pages without header and meta.