# apache shows forbidden error when no index.html file is found

Tags: apache

Hi,

When trying to access a directory with no index.html file it shows a forbidden error. It even ignores the index.php files. How can I fix this so the error is gone?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache?

Comment: I know how to do it with htaccess but I want to change it on the apache config so I dont need to create a htaccess file for each directory.

Comment: Then update your question asking precisely that

Comment: @CainNuke What do you exactly want? Do you want directory listing when index.html not available or you want to execute some other file?

Comment: I want the server to show no forbidden error and show the index.php file if present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to **create a default** `.htaccess` file in your Apache configuration?

If not, give it a try. More info about it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file) and [here](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/default-files-htaccess-and-php-ini).