# My website doesn't start on homepage.html

Tags: html

I published my first website! Everything looks great, however when you go to the website address, it doesn't start at the homepage.html, it starts at the contact page (index.php)? Can anyone help me with this? I wonder if it's starting there because it's my only PHP file? I know this has to do with my file paths but I am unsure how to fix it. Please help.

[www.eddiearkmunoz.com](http://www.eddiearkmunoz.com)

Comment: What web hosting platform are you using? How are you serving the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When no specific page is specified, the default page is used. Typically for a php web server, it is index.html, index.php or index.htm.

One fix is to rename the homepage.html to index.html and rename index.php to contact.php

A more complicated fix would be to reconfigure the websrever though in this case, it doesn't seem warranted.

Comment: You're the best! Problem has been fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rename `homepage.html` to `index.html`

Alternatively, look at this question to configure custom index page in Apache:
[How do I change the default index page in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache)

Answer (score 0):

You named your contact page "index.php", and "index.php" (or "index.html") is always the page that is loaded when you only use the directory URL as the adress. Just rename your pages: make the home page "index.php" and rename the contact page to something else like "contact.php".