# Prevent auto loading index.html from a folder

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

In my `/subwebpage/` folder I do contain an `index.html` file.

When im visiting my website like this: `www.website.com/subwebpage`
the `index.html` file **is loading automatically**. Even the URL don't display `www.website.com/subwebpage/index.html`

I would like to prevent the auto loading of the `index.html` file. This means, the `index.html` should only load, if the client is the URL: `www.website.com/subwebpage/index.html`

What do I have put into my `.htaccess` to do this?

**I tried with:**

```
# Deny access to everything by default
Order Deny,Allow
deny from all
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: in this post are a possible solution:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache)

Comment: @AlejandroGranados this link does not really answer my quesiton.

Comment: @EmbaBakar That SO question though should be your solution. If you change your default page to something else, like loadme.html, it won't load index.html unless you put it in the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the default index page in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the DirectoryIndex property in the .htaccess

This property tells the server which filename.filetype combination serves as the default file to be shown when none is provided. It can also accept multiple values separated by whitespace for fallback purporses i.e. if the first one is not found, check the second one etc.

The default property is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

To prevent your server from showing index.html by default, just change the index.html value of the DirectoryIndex property to something that does not exist, for example:

```
DirectoryIndex filethatdoesnotexist.html
```

---

---

---

For reference of what I mentioned, this this property can have multiple values separated by whitespace like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html default.html first.html
```

This means that if the server doesn't find the index.html it looks for default.html and if it doesn't find it either it looks for first.html etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But actually the .htaccess is in the folder `public_html/secure`. And the folder that I want to prevent to load `index.html` is on `public_html/secure/app`. In that case, where do I have to add this `DirectoryIndex`? One more quesiton: Does it have to be between `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>`

Comment: Just create another .htaccess file inside /public_html/secure/app

Comment: You can have as many .htaccess files as you want, every one that is in a nested folder will have priority before the one inherited from the parent folder(s).

Comment: And you do not need to put it inside <IfModule>, it can be just a one-line .htaccess file with the rule from above.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It works great, thank you a lot Ivica Pesovski!