# How to remove index.php from home page and .php extension from other php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to remove index.php from home page url
ex: `https://url.com/index.php`
change into
`https://url.com/`

and remove .php extension from other files

ex: `https://url.com/contact.php`

change into
`https://url.com/contact`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

You can append this to your `.htaccess` file to make all PHP files have their extension removed. You're required to have [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

As similarly seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite/1992191#1992191), adjusted to PHP.

Comment: Could you share your recent Apache error logs? Are you running from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Apache will automatically look for `index.php` if you enter a directory rather than a resource. So in that case, just don't type the `index.php` part. If you want to change it from the filename `index` to something else, you can modify the [DirecctoryIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache) in your `.htaccess` file.

In the case of `https://url.com/contact`, you can create a directory called `contact` and put your `index.php` file in that.

If you're passing arguments via the url and you don't want the user to see them, you can use javascript to [change what is shown in the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page).