# Configuring multiple sites in apache

Tags: php, windows, apache

I use Win10, Apache2.4 and PHP7.4. I created 2 test sites inside Apache24\htdocs - Test.com and Test2.com, both containing simple index.php files. Here are exceptions from config files:

hosts:

```
    127.0.0.1 Test.com  www.Test.com
    127.0.0.1 Test2.com www.Test2.com
```

httpd.conf:

```
    # PHP7 module
    PHPIniDir "C:/Dev/PHP-7.4.24"
    LoadModule php7_module "C:/Dev/PHP-7.4.24/php7apache2_4.dll"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
        ServerName www.example.com:80
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/Test.com"
        ServerName Test.com
        ServerAlias www.Test.com
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/Test2.com"
        ServerName Test2.com
        ServerAlias www.Test2.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

When loading both test.com and test2.com, browser shows folder index of htdocs. Only clicking on either index shows actual site, and browser address field become, for example, `http://test.com/Test.com/`. How to configure apache to show site from address like `test.com`?

Comment: Try without the _default_ Vhost block, does that work?

Comment: I tried to fully comment out this block - nothing changed.

Comment: And you restarted/reloaded Apache? You need to restart every time the configs change.. I suspect this might be the case..

Comment: No, I restarted apache with ```httpd -k restart```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the default index page in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache)

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

</VirtualHost
```

hey apache if you get any request on port 80 go to folder test.com

hey apache if you get any request on port 80 go to folder test2.com

doh !

so if i make a localhost request http://127.0.0.1:80 apache should just magically know which folder to go to right ???

Comment: The OP is using name-based virtualhosts (with a `ServerName` directive) and requesting the hostname, not the IP address. So it's not just "any request on port 80", it's "any request on port 80 where the `Host` header matches the value of the `ServerName` directive".

Comment: the ServerName directive is not going to fire because the OP is working on localhost, so they are  not requesting by domain name, hence why i say any request on port 80

Answer (score 0):

> When loading both `test.com` and `test2.com`, browser shows folder index of `htdocs`.

Ths will happen if the `ServerName` (or `ServerAlias`) directives do not match the requested `Host` header on the request. It will then *default* to the first `<VirtualHost>`.

> ```
> ServerName Test.com
> ServerAlias www.Test.com
> ```

I wouldn't necessarily expect this to be case-sensitive, but you've defined the `ServerName` as `Test.com` (capital `T`), but you are requesting `test.com` (all lowercase) - the browser automatically lowercases the hostname in the HTTP request anyway, so you can't actually make a request for `Test.com`.

You should be defining the `ServerName` as all lowercase.

```
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
```

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 Test.com  www.Test.com
> 127.0.0.1 Test2.com www.Test2.com
> ```

Likewise, this should also be lowercase.

> Only clicking on either index shows actual site, and browser address field become, for example, `http://test.com/Test.com/`

That looks like you are *incorrectly* linking to the `/Test.com` subdirectory, not the `http://test.com` host?

> I tried to fully comment out this block - nothing changed.

Do you have a similar *default* in the main server config, outside of a `<VirtualHost>` container?