# Block visitor from viewing Index of website?

Tags: html, dns

I am a college student building a website for a local band. I've recently noticed that when I navigate to the webpage folder using the domain (https://*insert website domain*.com/*folder name*) it show the "Index of" page and allows me to navigate the resources of the webpage. Is there a way to disable this through code, or is this a hosting issue?

Comment: it's because everyone has permission to view that folder.

Comment: So is this something where I would attempt to change the permissions of the folder through the hosting service?

Comment: yes, just change the permission of the folder on the hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. Add an *index page* in the folder, and the server will display that page instead. The name for the index page depends on the webserver you are using. For instances, most webservers will try to find `index.html`. You can also [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache).
2. [Disable directory listing](https://serverfault.com/questions/364561/how-to-disable-directory-listing) in your webserver settings. [The specific instructions](https://serverfault.com/search?q=disable%20directory%20listing) strictly depend on the webserver you use.